# Does "Set Transaction Level" require begin transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transactions, isolation-level

In MS SQL Server, if I use "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL" in a stored procedure, do I need to wrap the select statements in a BEGIN/END TRANSACTION Block? Will the following work as expected?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE my_sproc AS
BEGIN

    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

    SELECT * FROM MyTable

END
```

Comment: Please explain in your words what "as expected" is?

Comment: I would expect the select statement to behave as though I had used the (NOLOCK) hint. (Which I would do if my procedure were truly this simple)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` setting is a connection-level setting.  There's no need to wrap it in a transaction.

That being said, you understand you will have dirty reads and such from this setting?

You can accomplish the same thing on a query-by-query basis by using locking hints such as:

`SELECT * FROM MyTable WITH (NOLOCK)`

Answer (score 1):

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL is different to BEGIN/COMMIT/ROLLBACK

- The first changes the isolation vs concurrency settings
- The second defines the atomic "unit of work"

There is no direct link or interaction: different concepts